# DataGridview values not clearing and adding to newly inserted values

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have following code to add values in gridview

```
            int row = 0;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-2 ;
            dataGridView1["Description",row].Value = prod_name.SelectedItem.ToString();
            dataGridView1["Quantity", row].Value = txtQty.Text;
            dataGridView1["Price", row].Value = p;
            dataGridView1["Discountcell", row].Value = txtdisc_prod.Text;
            dataGridView1["amt", row].Value = tot;
```

and for clearing it I have tried different codes:
**1**

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                cell.Value = "";
            }
        }
```

**2**

```
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

values are clearing with both codes but when I add new values and calculate them, previous values are also adding with them. Following is my code for calculation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                float f, d, price;
                if (float.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["amt"].Value.ToString(), out f))
                {
                    gross_amt = gross_amt + f;
                }
                if (float.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["discountcell"].Value.ToString(), out d))
                {
                    dis_tot = dis_tot + d;
                }
            }
```

**Update** This is windows application

Comment: how about to make a new instance of DataGridView instead of clearing the content? Like this: `dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();` . You will loose the columns but you can make an initialize method and call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you declaring gross_amt and dis_tot? are you resetting these back to 0 (or what ever default number you want) before running the for loop? if not these will just keep adding from the previous loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Assuming it is a web based application  :  
You are not binding the grid with null data source:
    use this to clear out the data and bind them.

        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        ds = null;
        grd.DataSource = ds;
        grd.Update();

    IF you need to remove column name also use the below code snippet:

    for (int i = 0; grd.Columns.Count > i; )
    {
        grd.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

Comment: `DataBind();` no definition for it

Comment: is it winforms or webforms?

Comment: winforms. And I tried your code without this line but still same

Comment: in that case your data source may have some issues . can you share more details of remapping  the datasource

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191732/discussion-between-rami-far-and-rahul-sharma).